/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php Error 500 while using divi premade layout in existing pages
I am getting error as 500 while only using premade layout and existing pages option.
Its working fine for staging, issue is only on production.
How to check exact issue...
Tried disabling plugins..issue is not with plugins

Increase the memory_limit in the wp-config.php by adding:
define('WP_MEMORY_LIMIT', '256M');

Or,
go to your wp-config.php file in your root directory,
Change this line:
 define('WP_DEBUG', false);

to;
 define('WP_DEBUG', true);
 define('WP_DEBUG_LOG', true);
 define('WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY', false);

this will log any errors you're having with additional information in wp-content/debug.log file.
From your comment, it seems a process or theme/plugin is using too much memory. Deactivate inactive plugins. (Increase the memory to 512mb to enable you troubleshoot)

Current size is 256MB,
debug file error : PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 268435456 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 143360 bytes) in /www/onsurity_377/public/wp-includes/class-wpdb.php on line 2315
So how can I check where exact issue is coming and reduce memory utilization
